# Truncate a Mongo DB Collection from Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Is there a single method from MongoDB Java driver which deletes all documents in a collection ? so far I've only been able to do this by browsing a cursor and calling delete on each Document. Thanks

Comment: use the `collection.drop()` method on the `DBCollection` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("dbName");
DBCollection myCollection = db.getCollection("collectionName");
myCollection.drop();
```